# удаление из базы данных фокспро

Tags: delphi, база-данных, foxpro

не подскажете, в чем проблема:
в грид вывожу записи, при нажатии на строку хочу сделать удаление записи вообще из базы
вот так

```
DELETE FROM exp WHERE ide=exp.ide
SET DELETED ON 
PACK
thisform.grid1.refresh()
```

но он только помечает на удаление а не удаляет из базы

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Вроде бы там отдельная команда была, что-то типа Pack, не совсем понятно это все в одну строку команда? Попробуйте по одной команде на строку

Comment: Еще как вариант - транзакции. Commit попробуйте.

Comment: таблица открыта в Exclusive? без этого PACK не отработает (а эксепшн Вы, возможно, гасите где-то)

Answer (score 0):

Вы наступили на стандартные грабли, которые лежат перед всеми плохо понимающими логику фокса.
Замечания по коду:

1. Для удаления записей не надо переключать настройку set deleted. А судя по второй строке вашего кода вы это или делаете это где-то раньше, или у вас изначально стоит set deleted off, что в рабой программе выглядит как минимум странно.
2. Команда PACK работает только на эксклюзивно открытых таблицах, что, опять таки, выглядит очень странным в любой многопользовательской программе. Да и сам эта команда рассчитана на использовании в каком-нибудь административном/обслуживающем базу режиме, когда нет других пользователей и использование ее при интерактивной работе пользователя и есть наступание на упомянутые грабли. Кстати, если бы она срабатывала, то вы получали бы пустой белый грид.
3. Поставьте настройку set delete on дефолтной(по умолчанию) в вашей программе, уберите вторую и третью строки из вашего кода, перенесите команду pack в отдельный режим программы.

Answer (score -2):

Надо делать Close/Open DataSet'а

thisform.grid1.Datasource.DataSet.Close;
thisform.grid1.Datasource.DataSet.Open;

Comment: пожалуйста, давайте более развернутые ответы